# Is performing DUKPT encryption without a Pin Entry Device possible?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, tripledes

We have a web application and would like its users to enter PIN numbers for their debit cards in the web-based UI. However, we must be able to perform DUKPT key management and TDES encryption on the PIN number, and we are beginning to think that DUKPT will force us to use an actual, manufactured "PIN Entry Device", like a swipe card reading device.

This seems to be the case because the key management scheme requires the device to have a list of 'Future Keys' and/or a 'KSN'/'Key Serial Number'.

Does anyone know for certain if this DUKPT requirement will mean that we must enter PIN numbers via the PED all the time? If so, that will likely kill our hopes to have users enter them into a web page.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a [card security code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_Security_Code) for online transactions. Asking to enter card pin code anywhere except at atm or other "pin entry" physical device is 100% scam.

Comment: Appart from the PIN being sensitive data, which *you* should not know, there is also the issue with transaction authentication. If you know the PIN, you would be able to authenticate not just one transaction but multiple. So (not knowing the precise specs), this sounds like a **very** sensible security requirement.

Comment: Thanks folks...we came to the conclusion that it is not possible without specific pin entry devices.